# Time intervals in Postgres (SQL design)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to represent the following resource in SQL (PostgreSQL): accounts and clients. A client is an account that is purchasing product, for a given year. I need to know which years accounts are clients. This means representing discontinuous time intervals (e.g. 2001, 2003-2010, 2012-2014) in SQL.

My current approach is the following: an `ACCOUNT` table with attributes `id` and `name`, and a `CLIENT` table with attributes `id`, `account_id` and `year`. An account would get one entry in the `ACCOUNT` table and one entry for each year they purchased something, in the `CLIENT` table.

My problem with this approach is I feel like I am duplicating a lot of information. Some clients have discontinuous time intervals, but some have been clients non-stop for 20 years, meaning they have 20 entries in `CLIENT`.

An alternative approach I thought of was using an attribute `years` with an array of [ranges](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/rangetypes.html)  instead. However, this complicates queries. What would be the best approach?

Comment: I think the lookup table is your best choice. It makes querying the easiest thing. I wouldn't worry about "20 rows per client" in that table unless you have millions of clients

Comment: Your problem is that you are intending to store aggregates. Basically, a client (for a given period of time) **is** an `... account a where exists (select * from puchaces p where p.account_id = a.account.account_id AND p.puchace_date "... in the same period")`

Comment: The database does not store any detailed information about purchases (I don't have access to this), only whether accounts are clients (made a purchase) or not on a given year. I could change ACCOUNT table name to PURCHASE to conform more to what you mean.